# Safety update JDK 6.0 to JDK 7.0 on Windows 7

Tags: java, java-7

I have already JDK 1.6.0.0_25 on my computer with Windows 7 Professional.

[image]

How I can savety update current JDK to JDK 7.0 and tesing this update?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your CLI.  The text is what is important, and that can be copy/pasted (and searched on, since it is text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you install JDK 7 as well. You can have Java 6 installed as well and make this this default.  You can uninstall one or other version later.

Comment: Indeed. On my PC, I have it installed for testing purposes for about a year now (`ea-bin-b102` since July 2010, recently switched to `fcs` release). It sits right near Java 6 and is "visible" only in IDE where I play "dirty games" trying and testing new API. Routine programs don't even notice it, these all use  _default_ java 6. Never had a problem with that

Answer (score 3):

IMO a good way would be to download and install JDK 7 separately. If it works out fine for you, uninstall the previous one and update the environment variables accordingly (namely `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`). You can download the latest stable release [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Install Java 7. Uninstall Java 6 if it doesn't do that already. If there's an issue with Java 7, uninstall it, reinstall Java 6.

If you're really worried, make a backup. Or try installing it on a VM image of your machine first.